# iCalendar RRULE Recurring Events Custom Repeat

Tags: icalendar

I am trying to create 2 events that have custom repeats but I can't quite figure out the coding.

1. I need an event that happens every 30 days but if the 30th day is a weekend I'd like it to move to the following Monday. *But* I also need it to stay on the original 30 day cycle.
2. I also need an event that happens x week days before x day of the month.  For instance I'd like an event that happens 3 weekdays before the 15th of every month.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

My personal advice would be to avoid complicated RRULE's since not all ical applications handle them properly. I'd suggest writing a short computer program or something similar.

To clarify, I meant write a program that creates an iCalendar, but
lists dates explicitly instead of using an RRULE.

While there are several iCal creators online, I don't think any of
them will handle the complexity of the rules you need, especially the
first one.

You might find an RRULE for your second condition, but I found it
easier to simply write a program.

Overall, although RRULE is a nice tool, it can't do
everything. Sometimes, you just have to specify the dates yourself,
which also gives you more flexibility to use other calendar formats
which may not support RRULE.

I've now written:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-blank-ical.pl

and created these blank iCalendars per your date rules above.

http://oneoff.barrycarter.info/webapps-90641-1.ics

http://oneoff.barrycarter.info/webapps-90641-2.ics

Important notes:

- Be sure to check my work: make sure the dates in the calendar are
  the dates you actually want.
- For your first rule, I arbitrarily assumed the first event was on
  February 1st. You should tweak my program to generate the correct
  date (or contact me (see profile), and I can do this).
- For your second rule, I created events from 2016 through 2037
  inclusive.
- To use these calendars, search/replace all instances of `_SUMMARY_`
  with the actual summary of your event, all instances of
  `_DESCRIPTION_` with the description, and so on. The calendars I
  created only have dates and randomly generated UIDs.
- You should also change the PRODID of each calendar.

While I personally don't object, I'm not sure this question actually
belongs on webapps, since its not about an existing web application.

Comment: _"I'm not sure this question actually belongs on webapps..."_ I would tend to agree.

Comment: I wrote this answer in a Perl comment, and apostrophes confuse Emacs' Perl mode.... thanks for adding them for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, can you give an example. For instance do you want it to move to the next month if needed ?

For the second one, I'd suggest the following given x=2

> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=10,11,12;BYSETPOS=-1

What the rule does is to say it can happen:

- 3 days, 4 days or 5 days before the 15th (`BYMONTHDAY=10,11,12`)

  - 5 days in case the 3rd day before the 15th is a Sunday.
- Also you say that your occurence rules is only on weekdays  `BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR`
- out of the possible options in one month `FREQ=MONTHLY;`
- it will take the later one `BYSETPOS=-1`

E.g.:

- if the 13th is a Friday, the rule will return the 13th
- if the 13th is a Saturday, the rule will return the 12th
- if the 13th is a Sunday, the rule will return the 11th